# How can memory leaks cause information leak?

Tags: security, memory, memory-leaks

I am a little bit confused about this thing. I know that every program written in a language that does not use automatic garbage collection, has to free all of its resources before exiting, else memory leaks appear.

My question is, how these memory leaks lead to information leaks such as leaking passwords etc.?

My understanding is that after a program exits, the memory it was using can be reused or inspected by another program. So if that memory area was not cleared, it will contain some important information such as a password.

Comment: Please include the source that made you think so (seems likely from the language of the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is independent of memory leaks and garbage collection.

after memory is no longer needed its content is not removed, its just marked as free. this way if your application had a password in memory, it can stay there even after the program is quit.

to prevent such leakage of information you actively have to overwrite the spot in memory where you had some critical information stored.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that a memory which was used by a program might still contain interesting information after it terminated/exited.
That is however also true for a program which does not contain any memory leaks. Correctly freeing allocated memory does not clear it.

It is however very likely that any program which does not correctly free allocated memory, might also fail to safely delete information inside that forgotten/leaked memory.
Note that "leaked" in this case is referring to memory which did not get freed before end of program, ignoring the fact that such memory will be recovered by practically every modern operating system. The memory is available for use by other programs, especially programs being started later.
Operating systems which do delete explicitly or implicity freed memory are possible, but unlikely outside of dedicated security related use cases.

Above with "deleting explicitly" I mean the program itself writing irrelevant information before freeing. With "deleting implicitly" I mean freeing it is sufficient, the deleting happening somehow during `free()`.

I am using C as an example language, the tag was there but has been deleted (not unreasonably).

Garabge collection (in languages which imply it) does not change anything about this. Garbage collection (while releiving from the duty to correctly free memory) can implicitly overwriting newly reavailable memory, but do not guarantee it; exactly as the freeing mechanisms in languages without garabage collection.

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, it does not matter if a password was stored in an allocated memory area such as a char* or in a static array such as char[]....it will remain there regardless of freeing or not freeing

Comment: I can imagine environment in which freeing might imply/include overwriting of freed memory. As I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Merely freeing the allocated memory won't 'erase' the data from its position. However the destructors (pardon my c++ terminology) can be made such that they overwrite the data with gibberish (or 0s) to achieve that.

Comment: @G_S It seems that your comment completely agrees with my answer. I do not get the point. Apart from a valid example of how to implement sensibly an explicit overwriting of freed memory in C++.

Comment: Anyone who uses a contiguous block of memory to store a password needs a good talking to. Java has something specific for this, in C++ you can adapt `std::string` trivially.

Comment: @Bathsheba Valid point and in my opinion worth making a separate answer to shed light on an implicitly present angle of OPs question.